# GeoJSON layer on Google Maps API is not showing

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I am using the following codes to visualize a GeoJSOn on Google Maps API.

```
var geojsonFeature = {
                                    "type": "Feature",
                                    "geometry": {
                                      "type": "Polygon",
                                      "coordinates": JSON.parse(JSONobject[0].JSON).coordinates[0]
                                    }
                            };
                            var googleOptions = {
                                strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
                                strokeWeight: 7,
                                strokeOpacity: 0.75
                            };

                            var myGoogleVector = new GeoJSON(geojsonFeature, googleOptions);

                            if (myGoogleVector.error){
                                // Handle the error.
                            }else{
                                myGoogleVector.setMap(map);
                            }
```

Its returning the following error

> uncaught reference error GeoJSON is not defined

here is the GeoJSON fetching from database

```
[[[[-3.58466299999998,40.653534],[-3.58416399999999,40.645122],[-3.57777099999998,40.645808],[-3.56814799999995,40.643543],[-3.56669199999999,40.650369],[-3.55906599999997,40.650485],[-3.562074,40.645539],[-3.55856,40.642499],[-3.55641499999996,40.636165],[-3.56240699999995,40.637156],[-3.56385,40.634403],[-3.56028999999995,40.62432],[-3.55866899999995,40.624382],[-3.559326,40.612243],[-3.55188399999997,40.611541],[-3.54740999999996,40.613852],[-3.54317099999997,40.612906],[-3.53588499999995,40.616672],[-3.52996099999996,40.613629],[-3.52470799999998,40.614486],[-3.52360699999997,40.616052],[-3.51882999999998,40.615856],[-3.50475,40.62025],[-3.50232199999999,40.619824],[-3.50347599999998,40.625645],[-3.49253299999998,40.624856],[-3.486874,40.625408],[-3.48826199999996,40.61937],[-3.48614299999997,40.615703],[-3.47918699999997,40.613561],[-3.47633099999996,40.609201],[-3.47601399999996,40.604547],[-3.46338799999995,40.607617],[-3.457448,40.606575],[-3.45370599999995,40.60743],[-3.46489399999996,40.598167],[-3.46592699999997,40.595318],[-3.46756299999998,40.595986],[-3.47589299999999,40.59241],[-3.482843,40.587501],[-3.48226799999998,40.586469],[-3.48881599999999,40.58506],[-3.49518,40.585953],[-3.50831399999998,40.58232],[-3.52083099999999,40.581192],[-3.52729499999998,40.582836],[-3.52976099999995,40.582188],[-3.52989299999996,40.58424],[-3.53294899999997,40.58501],[-3.54014899999999,40.583977],[-3.53991399999995,40.582635],[-3.545323,40.583943],[-3.54951199999999,40.587284],[-3.55304899999999,40.586448],[-3.56139099999996,40.587875],[-3.561644,40.592727],[-3.56544099999996,40.592964],[-3.56566199999997,40.598347],[-3.57579699999997,40.601903],[-3.57759999999996,40.607995],[-3.57447999999999,40.610901],[-3.573981,40.618885],[-3.57977899999997,40.619304],[-3.58072199999998,40.623112],[-3.58449400000001,40.627281],[-3.58942199999996,40.633644],[-3.59164399999997,40.640263],[-3.58941299999998,40.644885],[-3.59190799999999,40.648937],[-3.59346299999999,40.654804],[-3.58933299999995,40.655884],[-3.58466299999998,40.653534]]]]
```

Comment: do you have a source for the geojson? (how was it created)

Comment: I have updated my question with GeoJSON values fetching by PHP and Ajax

Answer (score 3):

I used this web to validate GeoJSON: http://geojsonlint.com/

After pasting yours, I got:

```
Invalid GeoJSON
POSTed data was not JSON serializeable.
```

Try this link to test all your GeoJSON files to see where is the error.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have updated my question with GeoJSON values fetching by PHP and Ajax